# Wordpress custom post type to cart not update it

Tags: wordpress, cookies, woocommerce, custom-post-type, cart

I’m working on one client site, the previous developer uses WP custom post type build a product collection page, kind like woocommerce, but only can add to cart to request a quote to the company, no transaction on the cart application.

I have trouble with I can add to cart is fine, but when I view the cart page. the item won’t show up unless I refresh the page. same problem with delete item in the cart.

There’s a cookie set in the code, which I not familiar with, thinking might be the issue.

I thought I move the  to the top will fix some issue, but the cart won't work. I got some unexpected end error on WP debug tool, so I tried to use PHP checker to see how many } I miss and add it back, and still not working.

Thank you so much for the help!

**—–-- More Info ———-**

Wordpress version: 4.9.7
PHP server:        5.6
Theme development date: unknown (Twenty thirteen theme modify version, never update)

**—–-- code ———-**

```
<?php
    if(get_query_var('remove') > 0){
      $r = get_query_var('remove');
      $d = get_query_var('d');
      if (isset($_COOKIE['cart'])) {
        $cart = json_decode(base64_decode($_COOKIE['cart']), true);
        unset($cart[$r][$d]);
        if(empty($cart[$r])){
            unset($cart[$r]);
        }
        if(empty($cart)){
            setcookie("cart", base64_encode(json_encode($cart)), time() - 3600, '/');
        } else {
            setcookie("cart", base64_encode(json_encode($cart)), time() + 2592000, '/');
        }
        header('Location: '.get_the_permalink());
        die();
    } else {
        header('Location: '.get_the_permalink());
        die();
    }
 }
?>

<?php get_header();?>
<?php if(isset($ok) && $ok == 1){?>
      <p class='after_cart_text'>Thank you for the opportunity to quote your project!  We will endeavour to respond within 24 hours.</p>
<?php } else { ?>
<?php if(isset($ok) && $ok == -1){?>
    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert">Please check the the captcha form.</div>

<?php } ?>

    <div class="baners_categories">
      <?php
        $rows = get_field('banery_categories', 'options');
                if($rows){
                shuffle( $rows );
                $image = $rows[0]['picture_categories'];
                ?>
                <img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
                <?php
                }
                ?>
                </div>

</fieldset>
<fieldset>

<!-- Form Name -->
<p class="legend_pe"><legend>Product Information</legend></p>
<?php if(isset($_COOKIE['cart']) && !empty($_COOKIE['cart']) && $post->post_name == 'cart'){
$cart = json_decode(base64_decode($_COOKIE['cart']), true);
//var_dump($cart);
$i = 0;
if (is_array($cart)) {
foreach($cart as $k => $row){
  foreach($row as $k2 => $item){
        //var_dump($item);
?>

<!--  form section code I comment it out -->

      <?php }?>
        <?php }?>
    <div class="col-sm-4" style="margin-bottom:15px;">
        <p><strong>Your cart is currently empty.</strong></p>
     </div>

      <?php }?>
      <?php }?>
<?php }?>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Thank you so much for any helps or tips!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add this `<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>` end of the while loop and work now. More info here:https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_reset_postdata